# Is it possible to use Kotlin's capture in the when condition?

Tags: kotlin

I'm trying to do something like:

```
data class Data(val valid: Boolean)

fun main() {
    println("Hello, world!!!")
    when (val data = Data(true)) {
        data.valid -> println("Valid")
        else -> println("Invalid")
    }
}
```

But I'm getting an error:

```
Incompatible types: Boolean and Data
```

Is it possible to use `data` on the left side of `->`? I know I can do `is Data` so the variable is clearly in scope there, but is there another way to access it?

Comment: I don't think so, left side of [`when`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/control-flow.html#when-expression) only supports: equality, class check and range check. If you want to check boolean conditions you need to use argument-less `when`.

Comment: No.  You could separate the declaration of the variable and then write `when { data.valid -> ...`, but you can't integrate the definition of `data` into the `when`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use sealed classes. E.g.

```kotlin
sealed class Data {
    object Valid: Data()
    object Invalid: Data()

    companion object {
        
        fun create(valid: Boolean) : Data {
            return if(valid) {
                Data.Valid
            } else {
                Data.Invalid
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```kotlin
fun main() {
    println("Hello, world!!!")
    when (Data.create(true)) {
        is Data.Valid -> println("Valid")
        is Data.Invalid -> println("Invalid")
    }
}
```